# Termux says "'Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: termux

I have a problem and hope someone can help me. I am currently trying to write a script for Termux or Termux:Task. My script currently looks like this:

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
cd /./sdcard/www/public/
wp post list sleep 5
```

Every time I load the script I get the following error message:

`/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/wp: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.`

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for hours, unfortunately without success.

I am using an extension for Termux called "WordPress CLI". When I start termux and enter the commands individually, everything works. But as soon as I write the commands into a sh script and start it doesn't work anymore. :(

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is simple error you can fix it by replacing `!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash`. With `#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash`
Please tell if you get error again

Answer (score 0):

Try with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` in the shebang line.

> Termux-exec allows you to execute scripts with shebangs for traditional Unix file structures. So shebangs like #!/bin/sh and #!/usr/bin/env python should be able to run without termux-fix-shebang.

From https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-exec

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_do_I_keep_getting_a_%27/bin/sh_bad_interpreter%27_error?):

> Why do I keep getting a '/bin/sh bad interpreter' error?
>
> This error is thrown due to access script interpreter at nonexistent
> location.
>
> Termux does not have common directories like /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin at
> their standard place. There is an exception for certain devices where
> /bin is a symbolic link to /system/bin, but that does not make a
> difference.
>
> Interpreters should be accessed at this directory only:
>
> `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin`
>
> There are three ways to fix this:
>
> - Install termux-exec by using pkg install termux-exec. It won’t affect the current session, but after a restart should work without
>   any setup. Not needed if your Termux is up to date. If still not
>   working, try the next workaround.
> - Use command termux-fix-shebang to fix the shebang line of specified file.
> - Use termux-chroot from package proot to setup a chroot environment mimicking a normal Linux file system in Termux.

`termux-fix-shebang my_script.py` of second method work for me, which it modify the shebang(first line of `my_script.py`) from `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env python`. Since `/usr/bin/` is not exist in Android, that's why it throws the error `/usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. The other solution is run with `python my_script.py`, neither of `my_script.py` nor `./my_script.py`.

In my test, `termux-exec` of [the first method](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-exec) only work if I added correct shebang in main script(child OR child of child script no need) and ran command `export LD_PRELOAD=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libtermux-exec.so`.

And for the issue of this question, error shows `/usr/bin/env` in the middle with `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/wp` even though the shebang of script `#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash` looks ok, it means that `wp` command (located at `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/wp`) used inside the script contains shebang `#!/usr/bin/env wp` and should modify it to `#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/env wp` too. `termux-exec` of first method should fix this specific case too(already has correct shebang in main script).